# $and not returning any value mongodb

Tags: mongodb

[Here is the Screenshot of what i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4Qu.png)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#examples
the documentation which i referred but not working.

i tried running the same operations on online terminal too of tutorialspoint, its leading to the same results.

Is there anything wrong that i am doing? because according to the documentation of version 3.2.x , the $or operation which is given there, i am performing the same and its working,but $and is not working.

my mongodb version is 3.2.10

Comment: You can insert images into your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected. There is no document that fulfills both criteria. `$and` means that a single document must fulfill both criteria, but none of your documents even has more than a single field.

In the future, please post the code as code instead of referring to screenshots.

Comment: i actually wanted to find out whether both the conditions satisfy or not, i.e. is "ultrasonic" true and "fridge" false? then how am i supposed to do it? Little more help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish. You wanted to find out whether there is a document that has both `ultrasonic : true` and `fridge : false`. Since no such document exists, none are returned from the query, so you have found out what you wanted... What behavior do you expect?